# how to use modular system of netbeans platform?

Tags: netbeans, system, netbeans-platform, modular

i m new with netbeans platform , i want to use java class's method of module A into module B, so please suggerst to me how can i do deppendacy , Lookup system , and Service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetBeans class loading is partitioned, so each module gets its own class-loader. 
In order for you to use a class from module A in module B you need to set the package that your class is in as a `public package` and add Module A as a dependency for Module B

I would suggest looking at this [NetBeans platform quick-start tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html) - it covers the Lookup, module interaction and Service Provider usage.

The [Netbeans developer FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ) is also very helpful (For example it has a whole section for what the [lookup](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Lookup) is, and how to interact with it)